# Save text of label when viewing another view controller

Tags: ios, swift, view, controller

I have a simple app. It has a buttong which loads a View Controller named Info, which contains information about the app. On the Info View Controller there is a "Go Back" button which takes the user back to the main View Controller. On the main screen there is a label called countLabel which contains an Int, when going to the info screen and coming back the value of that Int resets to it's default of 0. How can I retain the value of that Int while on another screen?

```
//  ViewController.swift
//  Simple Count
//
//  Created by Jamie King on 11/19/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Jamie King. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var countValue = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    }
    @IBOutlet weak var countLabel: UILabel!


    @IBAction func countButton(_ sender: Any) {


        countValue = countValue + 1;
        update()
    }



    @IBAction func minusButton(_ sender: Any) {

     countValue = countValue - 1
        update()
    }



    @IBAction func resetButton(_ sender: Any) {

        countValue = 0
        update()    
    }



    @IBAction func infoButton(_ sender: Any) {



    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func update(){
        countLabel.text = "\(countValue)"
    }

}
```

Comment: Try using `self.countValue`instead of `countValue `

Comment: Added self.countValue but this doesn't seem to retain the value when returning from another View Controller.

Comment: Did you added it on your `update()` func? `countLabel.text = "\(self.countValue)"`

Comment: Yes I've updated the update function to include self.countValue

Comment: If it matters I've got a segue that loads the View Controller Scene named Info Scene which has a segue that returns to View Controller Scene (the main scene).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Save your count value in userDefault before switching to anothercontroller. like this

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
defaults.set(countValue, forKey: "count_value")
```

When you come back to your mainview controller get value for userDefault.

```
var countvalue = defaults.integer(forKey: "count_value")
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback but I'm at a loss for where I should add this code into? Thanks

Comment: on the tap of button when you load other controller.

Comment: Okay I've added this: `code` @IBAction func infoButton(_ sender: Any) {
        
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        defaults.set(countValue, forKey: "MyKey")
    }`code` and added the first set of code to AppDelegates but on returning the countValue returns to 0

Comment: just check when you are setting value whats the value of countvale , in appdelegate definitely countvalue will be zero, on returning to again mainview controller get value for userdefault, i see you are initialising countvalue to 0

Comment: This is a very bad solution. Very wrong. User defaults are for preferences and settings. Using it to pass data between views is a complete nonsense. Sure "it works" but it's ridiculous and one of the worst antipatterns. It's a waste of resources and can even be the source of future issues.

Comment: Hy  i agreed with you this is not a good approach, he need to use only one value,  @zakth for good approach please use a singleton class and save you count value within it. and every time when you come to your main controller just get value from your singleton class. thanks for pointing.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `self.countLabel`on your `func update()`

```
func update(){
        self.countLabel.text = "\(self.countValue)"
}
```

Comment: Okay, I've made this update but when returning to the main ViewController the counter resets to 0 instead of retaining the Int it previously held.